# How to save a title of a cell to an NSMutableArray when row is selected?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a table that needs to save the title of the cell selected to an array. My NSMutableArray is called dataArray and I'm using this line

```
        [categoryItemSelected addObject: dataArray];
```

to save the selected item(s). I would like more than one item to be added to the array - the user should be able to select as many or as few rows as they like. Each one would be added to the dataArray.

here's my table didSelectAtIndexPath: method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    int index = indexPath.row; id obj = [listOfCategories objectAtIndex:index];


    //This toggles the checkmark
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-tick.png"];

        UIButton *downloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [downloadButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [downloadButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 19, 19)];
        [downloadButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = downloadButton;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        //This sets the array

    } else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        UIButton *downloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [downloadButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [downloadButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = downloadButton;

    }

    // Save text of the selected cell:
    UITableViewCell *cellSelected = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cellSelected.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Food & Drinks"]) {
        NSString *valueToSave = cellSelected.textLabel.text;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];

    }

    NSString *valueToSave = cellSelected.textLabel.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];


    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];

    NSLog(@"savedValue %@", savedValue);

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    // Customize archiver here
    [archiver encodeObject:obj forKey:@"keyForYourArrayOfNSIndexPathObjects"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"keyForYourArrayOfNSIndexPathObjects"];


    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver;
    unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:
                  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"keyForYourArrayOfNSIndexPathObjects"]];
    // Customize unarchiver here
    categoryItemSelected = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"keyForYourArrayOfNSIndexPathObjects"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    if (categoryItemSelected == nil) {
        //If it isn't been created - then create new array

        [categoryItemSelected addObject: dataArray];

        NSLog(@"list of categories selected in dataArray %@", dataArray);

    }

    NSLog(@"list of categories selected in dataArray %@", dataArray);      

}
```

Comment: So, what's the question? What's not working with your current code?

Comment: That's a lot of code to put into a "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`" method.  Wouldn't it be smarter to save the titles to the mutable array and then do the archiving / unarchiving thing (whatever *that's* doing) when the user dismisses or pushes the view containing the table out of the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the parameters backwards.  To add this object to `dataArray` do:

```
[dataArray addObject: categoryItemSelected];
```

You need to check if categoryItemSelected is nil first, since inserting a nil object into an array will throw an exception.

Comment: thanks :) I tried that but         [dataArray addObject: categoryItemSelected]; outputs as (null) when I select items.

Comment: Then you have two bugs.  You probably are also not initializing your `dataArray`.  Try `dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in your init or viewDidLoad method.